# Assembly mips running a text reading program from console

Tags: io, mips

I have to write a program in mips assembly language that read a txt file and do some work with the information in it, the problem is that it must work from unix console using a command like this cat fileName.txt | java -jar Mars4_3.jar programName.asm.
Isn't cat the command to open and read a file? To open a file in assembly I need its name in a string with a null termination character, is this a typo or I'm missing something?

Comment: Sounds like whoever gave you the assignment wants the program to process data from the command line rather than from a file (if you do `cat filename | xargs some_program` you'd give the _contents_ of the file specified by `filename` as arguments to `some_program`). Maybe you should ask that your professor/supervisor for a clarification.

Comment: Does that means that you will give the whole file, in form of a string a presume, as input?

Comment: If `xargs` is used like in my example you'd get the file contents as 1 _or more_ argument(s). For example, if the file contained the line `foo bar` you'd get `foo` and `bar` as 2 arguments.

Comment: The command is exactly like the one I posted, xargs it's not used, considered that the file contains 32 lines it would be crazy to have all those arguments.

Answer (score 1):

By using pipes (`|`) you are telling to map *stdout* from the left command to *stdin* of the second command.
Therefore you have to use `syscall` 8 to read from *stdin*. Note that each time you issue a syscall 8 a complete line will be read (until a *newline*) so if your input has more than one line you will have to read them one line at a time.

This example reads one line from the input onto a buffer and the just prints it again:

```
.data
msg: .asciiz "Text: "
buffer: .space 16384  # Buffer size
.text
  li $v0, 8
  la $a0, buffer
  li $a1, 16384
  syscall  # Read text from stdin

  li $v0, 4
  la $a0, msg
  syscall

  la $a0, buffer  # Print read texto from stdin
  syscall

  li $v0, 10  # exit
  syscall
```

And test it like this (suppose fileName.txt contains the text 'This is a test!'):

```
cat fileName.txt | java -jar Mars4_3.jar programName.asm
Text: This is a test!
```

Comment: So it is just a big string made with all the content of the file, does it keep the new line character as well?

Comment: No, each syscall 8 will read one line at a time, including the newline character. So if you have say 50 lines, you will have to issue 50 syscalls to get all those lines

Comment: In the case that one of the line has to be taken as an int can I just use the syscall for reading an int or I have to parse it?

Comment: If your input file has an integer represented as a ASCII string you will have to parse it; what you will get by reading the line is the string representing the number.

Comment: Thank you, I'm grinding a bit of code now, I would have never figure that out.